# WebServiceHost: a Simple Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, user-interface, web-to-winforms

I just learn about WebServiceHost object in my other question. I am however reading and searching about it further. But is it possible to host a simple Website using Webservicehost or something similar? In my application I have to show a User Interface with some information, I have that interface already built up in ASP.NET and I have to recreate it in WinForm/WPF to be usable by my application. However I am thinking if my application can host WebApplication, then I probably can save sometime, and show the interface using Browser Component. I do not want to host website in IIS as we have some part which need to be done through core Windows application.

So, in short my question remain: is it possible to host website with WebServiceHost?

Comment: Firstly WebServiceHost is for web services not web sites. Secondly, why are you trying to avoid doing the work?

Comment: Answer to second thing is easy, I am Lazy and 4 month late on project. :) I understand WebServiceHost are for Services, but some of my webservices are created in multiple EndPoints too, so Do I have to start WebServiceHost for each EndPoint?

Comment: Most sane solution in your situation will be to port your UI to *WinForms/WPF*. Just make up how to do it right instead of finding out how to do things in unnatural way.

Comment: I was thinking what is the `we have some part which need to be done through core Windows application` part ?

Comment: it has a data analyzer screen, where we have graph, video, sound playing in sync. Some of these can be done using wpf easily for me than on web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebServiceHost is intended to host WCF services with web (read HTTP) focus, REST services and the like. Pages are not necessarily services, but content that could come from services.

I think you would fare better looking for some other client side hosting method, one approach here: http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/aspnetruntime/aspnetruntime.aspx

Useful links for WebServiceHost:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webservicehost.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/justinjsmith/archive/2007/07/02/webservicehost-vs-servicehost.aspx